# React Switch Route Default

Tags: react, switch, react-router

Estou criando uma app em NodeJs, React & Redux aqui na empresa. E tenho uma página que é a Content, nela tenho duas barras de navegação e uma área comum para o conteúdo. Nesta área comum estou utilizando o Switch para controlar as rotas, mas quero que uma rota (componente) entre logo quando a app é carregada, ou seja, seja a default, mas não estou encontrando documentação sobre isso, pode me ajudar, abaixo segue o código.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Topnavbar from './Topnavbar';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import Profile from './Profile';

const Content = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Fragment>
        <div id='wrapper'>
          <Navbar />
          <div id='content-wrapper' className='d-flex flex-column'>
            <div id='content'>
              <Topnavbar />
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
                <Route exact path='/profile' component={Profile} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Content;
```

Quero que o componente Dashboard seja o default. Como determinar que uma rota é a default no switch?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o componente `Redirect`.

Fica algo assim:

```
<Switch>
 <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} default />
 <Route exact path='/profile' component={Profile} />
 <Redirect exact from="/" to="/dashboard"/> 
</Switch>
```

Isso significa que quando a aplicação carregar (normalmente isso começa com "/") então você vai redirecionar para o "/dashboard".

Há também uma outra forma, que funcionava na v4 do `react-router`, mas não tenho certeza na v5.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} default />
  <Route exact path='/profile' component={Profile} />
  <Route render={() => <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>}/>
</Switch>
```

Colocar um componente `Route` sem `path` fará ele ser executado sempre. No entanto, como nesse caso ele se encontra na última ordem dentro de um `switch`, ele só será executado caso não passo por nenhum outro `Route` anterior.

Em outras palavras, caso o `path` vá para algum diferente de "/dashboard" ou "/profile" ele vai redirecionar para "/dashboard" sempre.

Comment: Obrigado Andrew, Utilizei o Redirect mas ao invés de uma "/" usei o "/content" to "/dashboard" por que minha aplicação usa o "/" para ir sempre para o login, uma vez que ela roda em uma intranet e tem a necessidade de sempre fazer o login para acessa-la.

Comment: Que bom que deu certo. 

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer isso:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/sua rota" exact component={seu componente aqui} />
</Switch>
```